# how to put multiple tables below the plot via ggplot

Tags: r

I tried to put multiple tables below the plot via ggplot and it worked. However, i am facing with a challenge that the tables are occupying more space and the plot height is reduced. is it possible to to reduce the height of the tables, so that the plot height is reasonable

Here is the data i have

```r
> dput(adlbsum)
structure(list(trta = structure(c("Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", "Xanomeline High Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose", 
"Xanomeline Low Dose", "Xanomeline Low Dose"), label = "Actual Treatment"), 
    trtan = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81, 
    81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
    54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54), label = "Actual Treatment (N)"), 
    avisit = structure(c("Baseline", "End of Treatment", "Week 12", 
    "Week 16", "Week 2", "Week 20", "Week 24", "Week 26", "Week 4", 
    "Week 6", "Week 8", "Baseline", "End of Treatment", "Week 12", 
    "Week 16", "Week 2", "Week 20", "Week 24", "Week 26", "Week 4", 
    "Week 6", "Week 8", "Baseline", "End of Treatment", "Week 12", 
    "Week 16", "Week 2", "Week 20", "Week 24", "Week 26", "Week 4", 
    "Week 6", "Week 8"), label = "Analysis Visit"), avisitn = structure(c(0, 
    99, 12, 16, 2, 20, 24, 26, 4, 6, 8, 0, 99, 12, 16, 2, 20, 
    24, 26, 4, 6, 8, 0, 99, 12, 16, 2, 20, 24, 26, 4, 6, 8), label = "Analysis Visit (N)"), 
    n = c(86L, 84L, 67L, 68L, 84L, 65L, 57L, 57L, 82L, 75L, 73L, 
    83L, 80L, 49L, 37L, 77L, 31L, 30L, 27L, 72L, 67L, 56L, 82L, 
    82L, 52L, 42L, 80L, 31L, 27L, 25L, 72L, 64L, 60L), mean_chg = c(0, 
    1.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0, 1.1, 1.6, 2.5, -0.4, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.5, -0.1, 
    1.4, -0.6, 1.2, 1, 1.9, -0.3, -0.2, 0.3, 0, 1.3, 1.1, 1.2, 
    -0.3, 1.6, 1.2, 1.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.6), CI_lower_chg = c(NaN, 
    0.4, -0.5, 0.2, -0.7, 0.3, 0.8, 1.8, -1.2, -0.7, -0.3, NaN, 
    -0.2, -0.8, 0.4, -1.2, 0, -0.1, 0.6, -1.1, -0.9, -0.7, NaN, 
    0.6, 0.2, 0.3, -0.9, 0.4, 0, 0.6, -0.5, 0, -0.3), CI_upper_chg = c(NaN, 
    1.9, 0.9, 1.6, 0.7, 1.8, 2.5, 3.3, 0.4, 0.7, 1.2, NaN, 1.3, 
    0.7, 2.5, 0.1, 2.5, 2.1, 3.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3, NaN, 2, 1.9, 
    2.1, 0.3, 2.8, 2.4, 3.1, 1, 1.6, 1.4), mean_aval = c(140.3, 
    141.5, 140.4, 141.1, 140.4, 141.2, 141.7, 142.6, 139.9, 140.3, 
    140.7, 140, 140.5, 140.2, 141.6, 139.1, 141.8, 141.6, 142.4, 
    139.7, 140.1, 140.5, 140, 141.1, 141.1, 141, 139.6, 141.4, 
    141.5, 142.1, 140.1, 140.6, 140.4)), row.names = c(NA, -33L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the code I used

```r
g1 <- ggplot(data = adlbsum, aes(x = reorder(avisit, avisitn), y = mean_chg)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=trta,color=trta), size = 1.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=trta,color=trta,linetype=trta), position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  # geom_line(aes(group = 1), color="lightblue",size=2) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = avisit, ymin = CI_lower_chg, ymax = CI_upper_chg, color=trta),
                position=position_dodge(width=0.7)
                ) +
  # geom_text(aes(label=mean_chg,y = mean_chg),data=adlbsum, position=position_dodge(0.7), size= 4) 
  theme_classic2() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# p2 <- ggtexttable(tab1[,names(tab1)!='trtan'], cols = NULL, rows = NULL)  

t1 <- ggplot(data=adlbsum) +
  geom_text(aes(y=trta, x=avisit, label=paste(as.character(mean_chg),as.character(mean_aval),sep='/'), hjust=1, vjust=0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Mean Change from Baseline/Mean Value") +
  #Thesame x-axis specifications as the above plot to ensure alignment
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,11,1), limits = c(0.5,10.5)) +
  #Reverse y-axis to show Group A to C instead of Group C to A
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 3), limits=rev) + 
  theme_classic(base_size=10) +
  #Remove axis line, ticks and axis label to get the look of a table
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(2,.8,2,.8, "cm"),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="white"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=11, hjust =0)
  )

t2 <- ggplot(data=adlbsum) +
  geom_text(aes(y=trta, x=avisit, label=as.character(n), hjust=1, vjust=0.5)) +
  # ggtitle("Number of Patients") +
  #Thesame x-axis specifications as the above plot to ensure alignment
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,11,1), limits = c(0.5,10.5)) +
  #Reverse y-axis to show Group A to C instead of Group C to A
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 3), limits=rev) + 
  theme_classic(base_size=11) +
  #Remove axis line, ticks and axis label to get the look of a table
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(2,.8,2,.8, "cm"),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="white"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=11, hjust =0, vjust = 0.9)
  ) + #coord_fixed(ratio=0.01) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) 


gridExtra::grid.arrange(gg1, t1,t2, ncol=1, nrow=3)
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace your use of `gridExtra::grid.arrange` with `patchwork::plot_layout(..., heights=, widths=)`.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, I tried `g1 + t1 + t2 + patchwork::plot_layout(ncol=1, nrow=3,widths = c(3, 3), heights = unit(c(7, 5), c('cm', 'cm')))`, but does not get me the desired output, the result is that the table occupy more space

Comment: There is a lot of gap between the title and table in both the tables that are appended, i need to find a way to reduce that gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`patchwork` and some changes to the theming helps here.

- I don't have `theme_classic2`, so I used `theme_classic`, likely a minimal change
- I removed the `plot.margin` theme elements in both tables, it was injecting the blank space that you say you don't way
- I also removed the `expand=` from the two tables, over to you how much this is useful
- You have `reorder(avisit, avisitn)` in your `g1` but not in `t1` or `t2`, which means the numbers in your tables are in a different order. Since we're manually controlling what goes where and it is feasible to have things silently misaligned, I strongly suggest you verify the numbers are associated with the correct x-labels in `g1`.
- You have `hjust=` and `vjust=` inside of the `aes(.)` calls; since you're using static values, you should move them outside of `aes(.)`.
- For your last request to move the table columns to be better aligned under the `g1` x-labels, I suggest `nudge_x=0.25` (or some number) for `t1`. (Over to you if you need the same in `t2`.)
- (Minor: I suggest you use `sprintf` to force your tables to use the same number of decimal places, so that `/140` and `/140.3` have the `/` aligned together ... perhaps not what you thought, but it's a visual nitpick on my part :-)

The modified plot/table code:

```r
g1 <- ggplot(data = adlbsum, aes(x = reorder(avisit, avisitn), y = mean_chg)) +
  geom_point(aes(group=trta,color=trta), size = 1.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=trta,color=trta,linetype=trta), position=position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  # geom_line(aes(group = 1), color="lightblue",size=2) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = avisit, ymin = CI_lower_chg, ymax = CI_upper_chg, color=trta),
                position=position_dodge(width=0.7)
                ) +
  # geom_text(aes(label=mean_chg,y = mean_chg),data=adlbsum, position=position_dodge(0.7), size= 4) 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# p2 <- ggtexttable(tab1[,names(tab1)!='trtan'], cols = NULL, rows = NULL)  

t1 <- ggplot(data=adlbsum) +
  geom_text(aes(y=trta, x=reorder(avisit, avisitn), label=paste(as.character(mean_chg),as.character(mean_aval),sep='/')), hjust=1, vjust=0.5, nudge_x = 0.25) +
  ggtitle("Mean Change from Baseline/Mean Value") +
  #Thesame x-axis specifications as the above plot to ensure alignment
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,11,1), limits = c(0.5, 11)) +
  #Reverse y-axis to show Group A to C instead of Group C to A
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +  # expand = c(0, 3)
  theme_classic(base_size=10) +
  #Remove axis line, ticks and axis label to get the look of a table
  theme(
    # plot.margin = margin(2,.8,2,.8, "cm"),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="white"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=11, hjust =0)
  )

t2 <- ggplot(data=adlbsum) +
  geom_text(aes(y=trta, x=reorder(avisit, avisitn), label=as.character(n)), hjust=1, vjust=0.5) +
  # ggtitle("Number of Patients") +
  #Thesame x-axis specifications as the above plot to ensure alignment
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,11,1), limits = c(0.5,10.5)) +
  #Reverse y-axis to show Group A to C instead of Group C to A
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev) +  # expand = c(0, 3)
  theme_classic(base_size=11) +
  #Remove axis line, ticks and axis label to get the look of a table
  theme(
    # plot.margin = margin(2,.8,2,.8, "cm"),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="white"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=11, hjust =0, vjust = 0.9)
  ) + #coord_fixed(ratio=0.01) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

And the `patchwork` combine:

```r
library(patchwork)
g1 / t1 / t2 + plot_layout(heights = c(8,1,1))
```

[image: ggplot2 patchwork layout]

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, appreciate your help. could you please let me know how to adjust the table values so they align exactly below the tick values, now the values in the table are slightly left aligned , may be if they move to bit to right especially the value of mid table, any thoughts

Comment: I just found another mistake in your code: in `g1` you use `x=reorder(avisit,avisitn)` but in the others you do not, and since you omit labels on the tables, we don't see that they are wrong (and they are in different orders).

Comment: As for your text-alignment thing, you're right-aligning them with `hjust=1`; if you change that to `hjust=0.5` then they are better aligned, though (I think "obviously") not exactly what you want ...

Comment: See my alternate suggestion of using `nudge_x`, which preserves your right-aligned numbers. @jkatam

Comment: 1 last question, when i use the patchwork, the y axis label of the first plot is pushed back, it is evident from the image as well, not sure how to bring it close to the y axis

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. It's technically an intentional feature in that axis labels and such are aligned across plots. Not sure, will think about it.

Comment: I've thought about it more, and I more believe that this is an intentional step taken by `patchwork`. [One thought](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html) suggests `wrap_elements(g1) / t1 / t2 + ...`, but that mis-aligns the x-ticks, perhaps one can work on `area(.)` to manually force this to work (see `?plot_layout` and `design=c(area(..),...)`.

Comment: Another thought: to `g1`, add `scale_y_continuous(name=NULL) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1, 11), clip="off") + geom_text(aes(x, y, label=lbl), data=data.frame(x=0, y=1, lbl="mean_chg"), angle=90)`. It's perhaps a little fragile (e.g., hard-coding `xlim=` and setting `clip="off"`), but it gets the job done _here_. (`clip=` is for clipping things outside of the plot area ... it can affect how other portions of the plot appear, so don't use it without verification.)

Comment: Thank you. alternatively, we need to update the `theme` as below for the first plot in ggplot `theme(axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=-80)))`.